# Python-sqlite3 : How to put a python variable in SELECT statement

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

How can I put a python variable just after the SELECT. The idea is to create a python function with three arguments where you can choose what you what (here, it's the age) from whom (here, it's Mike and James)

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.s3db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people
                (id INTEGER,
                 name TEXT,
                 surname TEXT,
                 age INTEGER,
                 alone INTEGER DEFAULT 0);''')

def add_people(id, name, surname, age, alone=0):
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO people (id, name, surname, age, alone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [(id, name, surname, age, alone)])
    conn.commit()

add_people(1, 'SMITH','James',45)
add_people(2,'JOHNSON','Mike',75)

cur.execute('''SELECT (?) FROM people WHERE surname = (?) OR surname = (?)''', ('age','Mike', 'James'))
print(cur.fetchall())
```

My code `return`:

```py
[('age',), ('age',)]
```

instead of :

```py
[(75,), (45,)]
```

EDIT : I want that what is selected is a variable and not directly written in the query. My goal is to make a function like this one :

```py
def query(what, who_1, who_2):
    cur.executemany('''SELECT (?) FROM people WHERE surname = (?) OR  surname = (?)''', (what, who_1, who_2))
    return cur.fetchall()
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: As written here, `executemany` is doing no more than `execute` would and `global` is not necessary.

Comment: Indeed, "global" is useless here. I've understood that execute() works for only one variable and I had to use executemany() for using more than one variable but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This takes the data you need as argument of select_data_of

```
import sqlite3


def add_people(id, name, surname, age, alone=0):
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO people (id, name, surname, age, alone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [(id, name, surname, age, alone)])
    conn.commit()


def select_data_of(names, data="age"):
    select = []
    for name in names:
        cur.execute(f'''SELECT [{data}] FROM people WHERE surname = (?)''', (name, ))
        select.append(cur.fetchall()[0])
    return select


with sqlite3.connect('test.s3db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people''')
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people
                    (id INTEGER,
                     name TEXT,
                     surname TEXT,
                     age INTEGER,
                     alone INTEGER DEFAULT 0);''')
    add_people(2,'JOHNSON','Mike',75)
    add_people(1, 'SMITH','James',45)
    data = select_data_of(("Mike", "James"), data="age")
    print(data)
```

OUT:

[(75,), (45,)]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not reply to what I'm asking. I want 'age' to be a variable and not be written directly in the query. I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, I'lltry to fix this asap.

Comment: I think this should answer to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your select query is wrong because of the 'ages' parameter, this new query will work.

Try

```
cur.execute("SELECT [age] FROM people WHERE surname = 'Mike' OR surname = 'James")
```

Comment: Can you elborate to explain how does it answer the question?

Comment: I think the `select` query was simply wrong because of the 'ages' parameter, I think this new query will work.

Comment: add this to your answer @BeChillerToo